# Thread-safe implementation of max

Tags: java, thread-safety, java.util.concurrent

I need to implement global object collecting statistics for web server. I have `Statistics`  singleton, which has method `addSample(long sample)`, which subsequently call `updateMax`. This has to be obviously thread-safe. I have this method for updating maximum of whole Statistics:

```java
AtomicLong max;

private void updateMax(long sample) {
    while (true) {
        long curMax = max.get();
        if (curMax < sample) {
            boolean result = max.compareAndSet(curMax, sample);
            if (result) break;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Is this implementation correct? I am using java.util.concurrent, because I believe it would be faster than simple `synchronized`. Is there some other / better way to implement this?

Comment: I appreciate Jon Skeet's comment about trying the synchronized version first.  I'm not convinced that holding a lock is going to be any more expensive that repeatedly banging on the `volatile Long` that `AtomicLong` holds.

Comment: @EdwardThomson AtomicLong.get() is implemented as a volatile read, which on most hardware is basically "free", roughly as expensive as a regular non-volatile memory read. Volatile writing/CAS is the slow part. A single volatile write/CAS in turn are both roughly twice as fast as a synchronized block when contention is low. See e.g. http://mailinator.blogspot.nl/2008/03/how-fast-is-java-volatile-or-atomic-or.html and http://www.evanjones.ca/lmax-disruptor.html

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As of Java 8, [LongAccumulator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/LongAccumulator.html) has been introduced.
It is advised as

> This class is usually preferable to AtomicLong when multiple threads
>   update a common value that is used for purposes such as collecting
>   statistics, not for fine-grained synchronization control. Under low
>   update contention, the two classes have similar characteristics. But
>   under high contention, expected throughput of this class is
>   significantly higher, at the expense of higher space consumption.

You can use it as follows:

```
LongAccumulator maxId = new LongAccumulator(Long::max, 0); //replace 0 with desired initial value
maxId.accumulate(newValue); //from each thread
```

Answer (score 13):

I think it's correct, but I'd probably rewrite it a little for clarity, and *definitely* add comments:

```
private void updateMax(long sample) {
    while (true) {
        long curMax = max.get();
        if (curMax >= sample) {
            // Current max is higher, so whatever other threads are
            // doing, our current sample can't change max.
            break;
        }

        // Try updating the max value, but only if it's equal to the
        // one we've just seen. We don't want to overwrite a potentially
        // higher value which has been set since our "get" call.
        boolean setSuccessful = max.compareAndSet(curMax, sample);

        if (setSuccessful) {
            // We managed to update the max value; no other threads
            // got in there first. We're definitely done.
            break;
        }

        // Another thread updated the max value between our get and
        // compareAndSet calls. Our sample can still be higher than the
        // new value though - go round and try again.
    }
}
```

EDIT: Usually I'd at least *try* the synchronized version first, and only go for this sort of lock-free code when I'd found that it was causing a problem.

Comment: @Jon: Whenever I see something like this, I'm always concerned about the looping.  I feel like yes, it will work, but I feel like it opens the door for a bunch of threads to come in here at once and all end up looping continuously because the value is constantly being updated.  How justified is this concern?

Comment: @Erick: They won't be able to loop *continuously*. Each iteration, either *this* thread quits, or a *different* one will - because we only continue the loop if the value has been updated, which means a different thread has successfully updated it.

Comment: @Jon Thanks for great answer, your code is indeed clearer and comments are perfect

Comment: @Erick: Just to ease your pain: in this example, it is clear that the value can only go up. Say Alice calls `updateMax(5)`, Bob calls `updateMax(3)` and Charlie calls `updateMax(1000000)`. The max value will only be update a maximum of three times - once per thread. The order matters very little. Either it will be updated to 3, then to 5, then to 1000000, or it will be updated to 3 and then to 1000000 or to 5 and then to 1000000 or it will only be updated once to 1000000. Remember - once curMax >= sample, the current thread will be finished.

Comment: I just found out about [codereview stack exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) maybe this question should be moved there?

Comment: @saberduck: Maybe - not sure. I don't hang out there, I'm afraid, so I don't really have a feel for the border.

Comment: This still makes me nervous.  I understand in principle why it works.  I guess I just feel like this approach loses a bit of control of thread management.  I'm not saying it's not the best solution, but I'd like to get to a place where I'm comfortable with it.

Comment: Now it seems that Java 8 provides ready-made solution for this problem http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/LongAccumulator.html

Comment: @saberduck: All kinds of things are going to be simpler with a more functional emphasis on Java :)

Comment: @JonSkeet I know it's been a while but if you declare the `setSuccessful` outside the loop and change the loop condition to `while (!setSuccessful)`, IMHO, it expresses the intent better than `while (true)` and you can eliminate the conditional `break` as well.
p.s: Conventionally `setSuccessful` should be `isSuccessful` :)

Answer (score 8):

With Java 8 you can take advantage of functional interfaces and a simple lamda expression to solve this with one line and no looping:

```
private void updateMax(long sample) {
    max.updateAndGet(curMax -> (sample > curMax) ? sample : curMax);
}
```

The solution uses the `updateAndGet(LongUnaryOperator)` method.  The current value is contained in `curMax` and using the conditional operator a simple test is performed replacing the current max value with the sample value if the sample value is greater than the current max value.

Comment: You may want to optimize it as `max.updateAndGet(curMax->Math.max(sample, curMax));`

Answer (score 3):

as if you didn't have your pick of answers, here's mine:

```
// while the update appears bigger than the atomic, try to update the atomic.
private void max(AtomicDouble atomicDouble, double update) {
    double expect = atomicDouble.get();
    while (update > expect) {
        atomicDouble.weakCompareAndSet(expect, update);
        expect = atomicDouble.get();
    }
}
```

it's more or less the same as the accepted answer, but doesn't use `break` or `while(true)` which I personally don't like.

**EDIT:** just discovered `DoubleAccumulator` in java 8.  the documentation even says this is for summary statistics problems like yours:

```
DoubleAccumulator max = new DoubleAccumulator(Double::max, Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY);
parallelStream.forEach(max::accumulate);
max.get();
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you did is correct, but this is a simpler version that I also think is correct.

```
private void updateMax(long sample){
      //this takes care of the case where between the comparison and update steps, another thread updates the max

      //For example:
      //if the max value is set to a higher max value than the current value in between the comparison and update step
      //sample will be the higher value from the other thread
      //this means that the sample will now be higher than the current highest (as we just set it to the value passed into this function)
      //on the next iteration of the while loop, we will update max to match the true max value
      //we will then fail the while loop check, and be done with trying to update.
      while(sample > max.get()){
          sample = max.getAndSet(sample);  
      }
}
```

Comment: This could temporarily downgrade the maximum: if sample is 6 max.get() returns 5, then somebody updates to 7, you will set 6 (returning 7). The next while loop will see 7 > 6 and set it (as expected). Result is that max will be 5 7 6 7.

Comment: yes, please remove "sample =". From java doc of getAndSet method "Atomically sets to the given value and returns the old value."

Comment: @eckes is correct, but there's no guarantee that the order will be as he/she says.  it could be `6>5`, `7>5`, `sample=7`, `7>7`, `sample=6`, `6>6`, and at the end, `sample` will be 6 and not 7...  why is 6 afraid of 7?  because 7 8 9.  no more!  6 just ate 7!